# What does <m,n> in maths represent?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I found this in my book,

A={<m,n>|m,n ε V}

V is some set of numbers.

And what is this type of representation called?

[part of the paragraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1ihw.png)

Comment: [Ordered pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair)

Comment: Quite likely an ordered pair, but you should check the book, which almost certainly describes notation it uses.

Comment: Notation varies from author to author.  In some cases $\langle m,n\rangle$ may simply refer to an ordered pair of objects.  In others it may more specifically imply that such an ordered pair is being treated as a vector.  Alternatively still, perhaps it is notating an inner product or perhaps even something else not mentioned.  Context is key.  As for what "*this type of representation called*", those are "angle brackets" (*not to be confused with curly brackets { }, square brackets [ ], or parentheses ( ) though these are also commonly used for similar purposes*)

Comment: Could also mean an interval.

Comment: its actually from a research paper on the Travelling salesman problem,

Comment: Edges in a graph. V is a set of vertexes.

Comment: yeah got it, thank you so much